# Upload invoice amazon MWS

Tags: amazon-mws

[image: screenshot sellercentral]
About which Webservice is it possible to upload a pdf invoice for an order?

Since some weeks it is possible to about via sellercentral or third party software. But I can not find a way about mws api.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Since all the answers are referring to the VAT Calculation Service while OP is clearly asking how to upload an invoice PDF through the API *without* VCS, and the only correct answer has been downvoted and deleted, [here is the link to the documentation](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/03/B2B/invoice-uploader-developer-documentation.pdf) . TL;DR: Use the `_UPLOAD_VAT_INVOICE_` feed type, set some addition feed options and the PDF as the feed content. I've flagged the correct answer to be restored, if that doesn't happen I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check this guide

https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/B2B/DeveloperGuide/vat_calculation_service__dev_guide_H383rf73k4hsu1TYRH139kk134yzs.pdf

"Once invoices have been generated, they must be uploaded to Amazon through the Feed type _UPLOAD_VAT_INVOICE_ in the Feed API"